# TypeError: Cannot read the property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, typeerror

I've been trying to make my discord bot to add roles to members on my server, but whenever I run my command, it doesn't work and always says:

> TypeError: Cannot read the property 'add' of undefined

I've even tried replacing `.add()` with `.addRole()`, but nothing has worked.

Here is my code:

```js
command(client, 'add', (message) => {
  const target = message.mentions.members.first
  const role = message.mentions.roles.first

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('RANDOM')
  .setDescription(`Added the role ${role}`)

  .then(target.roles.addRole(role));
  })
console.log('Commands are set')
```

Comment: What's your `discord.js` version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of errors:

- `mentions.members` and `mentions.roles` return collections that have a [`first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setDescription) method (not a property, so you'll need to add parentheses)
- you don't handle errors
- you don't check if there is a mentioned role and a member
- [`.setDescription()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setDescription) doesn't return a promise but a `MessageEmbed`
- inside `.then()` you should pass a function but instead you call `.addRole()` and pass a value
- if you're using discord.js v12, `addRole()` is simply `add()` now

Check out the code below:

```js
command(client, 'add', async (message) => {
  // first is a method not a property
  const target = message.mentions.members.first();
  const role = message.mentions.roles.first();

  // if something is missing, send an error message
  if (!role) return message.channel.send('You need to mention a role');
  if (!target) return message.channel.send('You need to mention a member');

  try {
    // add the role
    await target.roles.add(role);

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .setDescription(`Added the role ${role}`);
    message.channel.send(embed);
  } catch (err) {
    console.err(err);
    message.channel.send('Oops, there was an error. Maybe try again?!');
  }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.then(target.roles.addRole(role));
```

should probably be

```
.then(() => target.roles.addRole(role));
```

beyond that, you need to figure out why `target.roles` is undefined.  You could start by logging `target`.